# Is increased programming efficiency in Java or C# a myth?

Tags: c#, java, c++

A big advantage of Java or C# in increasing **productivity of development** is that you're supposed to lose less time with complicated language features, especially those related to memory management. But is it just an impression?

I think that the learning curve for C++ is definitely more steep, but for a proficient C++ programmer, and given a set of coding standards for C++, isn't the difference between Java and C++ fading away?

Comment: Watch out - you're about to be ambushed by a load of "This needs to be community wiki" comments.

Comment: Probably a well-intentioned question, but also a guaranteed opening shot in a flamewar. Also too subjective to be meaningfully answerable.

Comment: Umh, subjective I think.

I think there's a lot to be gained in productivity moving from C++ to managed OO languages. Event more with managed functional ones.

Comment: So what you're asking is, if you bastardize your C++ environment, isn't the difference between Java and C++ fading away?  Generally the language choice should be dependent on the problem.  If you need capabilities outside of Java or C#, C++ often satisfies your needs.

Comment: Ever tried to do GUI in C++? MFC anyone? OMFG! WHY oh why oh why would someone chose C++ for that?

Comment: Since this question was closed, I'll add my answer here in the comments.

C# and Java represent higher level languages than does C++ and therefore allow many problems to be solved more easily.  Likewise, the .Net and Java development platforms provide beneficial abstractions which remove some of the lower level concerns that C++ developers face.  There are pros and cons to each of these languages and the level of productivity offered depends on what the task at hand is, but for general purpose LOB apps, languages such as Java and C# will generally be more productive avenues than C++.

Comment: Too bad this question is closed :( http://www.gphipps.com/technology/spegrp.pdf is "Comparing Observed Bug and Productivity Rates for Java and C++" and concludes that "C++ produces between 200%
and 300% more bugs per hour. Java is also between 30%
and 200% more productive."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> for a proficient C++ programmer

This is the problem.  In my experience, most programmers are NOT proficient.  Java allows mindless assembly line workers to be productive in a way that C++ does not.

Proficient developers will be productive no matter what language they write with.

Comment: Try wrting in Malbolge then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge

Answer (score 2):

Higher level languages mean you have to do (and worry about) less crud which definitely *does* speed up development time for some applications (GUIs, web apps etc.). If you're writing lower level stuff though like device drivers I've found I waste as much time trying to go into and out of managed / unmanaged code (in the case of C++ / CLI) as I would probably have saved.

If anything, I would suggest higher level languages like C# and Java are becoming better for stuff which was traditionally only the realm of C++ as more and more libraries and wrappers for low-level control are written, developed and optomised.

So my advice; if you're doing higher level development, use a higher level language. If you need more control, use a lower level language (or find a high level one with some nice wrappers for your low-level tasks).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion no. Java and C# are simpler and safer and therefore faster to write. Of course if a C++ programmer has a certain level of skill, it is possible that there is no difference. But I think that's one of the reasons Java and C# can offer better productivity overall. You don't have to be a especially skilled programmer to be productive. And there are a lot more average programmers around than skilled ones.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that logic apply to any language? I think idea (whether true or not) is that the time from novice to proficient is less on average with Java or C# than with C++.

Also, I would tend to agree, on the surface. However, there are so many details on both sides of the debate that I promise you it won't be settled via a SO thread.

Comment: I agree. If this question lived long enough, there'd be someone popping up to argue that a proficient FORTH programmer can be more productive than *anybody* else. He might be right, but that is WHOLLY besides the point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course, but exactly that learning curve is the heart of the discussion.

The discussion is not about comparing two proficient developers, one in C++ and one in Java. Given that situation, a C++ developer has much less boilerplate to write, and might be even more productive.

When referring to managed platforms such as Java and .NET, it is very clear that a novice programmer can much more easily dive into things, and produce a working application in less time than it would take in C++.

Keep in mind that most of the programmers in the world are not proficient ones. They most likely are under-educated, have not gone through significant training, and have a deadline to meet.

Given that scenario - would you choose to hire 5 novice C++ programmers, or 5 Java/C# programmers - to get the job done?